# Configuring a VPS for multiple websites with automatic backups

Tags: vps

I'm configuring for the first time a VPS service and I'm wondering how I could setup automatic backups of my websites.

Should I let handle it by apache ? Or operating system level ?

Also, is there something I should know about configuring a VPS for multiple websites ?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm doing that every week with a shell script that creates a TAR file in /root and copies it using SCP.

It creates on files per mysql database, copy your local ldap directory if you have one.

It requires that you have a destination machine on which you can connect with a SSH key that's installed on your local machines.

With those assumptions satisfied, here is the script.

http://jve.linuxwall.info/ressources/code/bkp_sender.sh

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your configuration and your aim. Do you have mysql? Only static pages and PHP scripts?

As a minimum, you could use rsync to copy your files from your VPS to another place. It's quite standard and very flexible.